# omitting else in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, if-statement

I found some related to my question, but not exactly fit.

In algorithm using if statement, as I know we can omit else statement when we have no execution for false against condition.
For example, if A > B then (statement)
             end 
However, I want to know if we can omit only "else" like this.
If A > B then (statement), (else omitting point) (statement2)

Is it ok to use like this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not entirely clear on what your question is. Can you clarify? Do you mean that statement2 is to be executed whether true or false?

Comment: Is this a question about a specific programming language? If I understand your question correctly, this would not be OK as statement2 would be executed in all cases.

Comment: if (<condition>) ; else <statement2>;

Comment: The syntax of the language you're using depends on the language that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(condition)
 statement1;
else 
 statement2;


if(condition)
 statement1;
//omit else
statement2;
```

Is this what you want to do? If yes, then no, you can't do that.
In the first case, statement2 is executed only if the condition provided in if is not satisfied. In the second case however, statement2 is executed in all scenarios i.e if the condition is true or false. hence you shouldn't do this unless you want it to behave that way.